# ERB render expression as string

Tags: ruby, erb

Is it possible to not render a specific tag as ruby and instead as a string? The erb template is called using `ApplicationController.new.render_to_string()`

For example:

I'd like to have a tag `<% unsubscribe %>` render to `<% unsubscribe %>` instead of trying to evaluate the variable `unsubscribe`. However, for all other tags I'd like it to render as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is no. You either:

1. replace `<` and `>` with the equivalent html codes `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which looks like `&lt;% unsubscribe %&gt;`,

or

2. make your ruby statement print the string: `<%= '<% subscribe %>' %>`

Comment: Ah, THAT is what they meant.

Comment: I think the second one will cause syntax error issues because it will still try to evaluate the nested `<% ... %>`. That being said if the variable `unsubscribe` is set to the string `"<% unsubscribe %>"` it will work fine